# De Moivre's Theorem and a related formula?

Tags: complex-analysis

$$(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta), n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

is De Moivre's Theorem. It is useful in calculating integer angle trigonometric identities such as $\cot(4\theta)$ by taking the real part of $(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^4$ divided by its imaginary part, both parts obtained using binomial expansion.

However, from another post on this site, I've also seen that you can calculate $\cot(4\theta)$ by taking the real part of $(1+i\tan(\theta))^4$ divided by its imaginary part, likewise both parts obtained using binomial expansion.

So does that mean $(1+i\tan(\theta))^n=1+i\tan(n\theta)$? What's the relation between this formula and De Moivre's theorem?

Does this also mean I can flip the formulae to give me $(\sin(\theta)+i\cos(\theta))^4$ or $(\tan(\theta)+i)^4$ and take the imaginary part divided by the real part this time to still get the same answer for $\cot(4\theta)$?

Comment: It's not true that $(1+i\tan\theta)^n=1+i\tan(n\theta)$. Consider $n=2$ and $\theta=\pi/6$.

Comment: If $a+i b = x + iy$ for reals $a, b, x, y$, then $a=x$ and $b = y$.  Which of course implies $a/b = x/y$ or any number of such things.  Not clear how you have extended that logic to $(1+i \tan \theta)^n$ etc.

Comment: *"... from another post on this site ..."* – a link to that post would be helpful for the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this may clarify.

$$(1+i \tan \theta)^4 = \sec^4 \theta (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^4 = \sec^4\theta (\cos 4\theta + i \sin 4\theta)$$
where we have used a variant of deMoivre's theorem in the last step.  This also means, as the ratio of real to complex parts of the RHS is $\cot 4\theta$, you can use binomial theorem on the LHS and find the same ratio there to get an equivalent expression.

It does **not** imply $(1+i \tan \theta)^4$ is the same as $1 + i \tan 4\theta$.